# Typescript how to output logs

Tags: typescript

I have a problem where my typescript complier is running out of memory and crashing. I want to have a look at what is going on. The documentation says:

```
--verbose   boolean
Enable verbose logging
```

However this throws an error on `"typescript": "^4.2.4"`:

```
tsc --verbose
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '--verbose'.
```

Does anyone know how I turn on logging? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [advanced tsconfig options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Advanced_Options_6178). Depending on your problem, one of them may be illuminating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me while to figure this out because the error message is super unhelpful. Now they've finally updated the error message to be clearer, and it says that the `--verbose` flag has to be used with `--build`. So just run this:

```sh
tsc --build --verbose
```